# Issue with Booth multiplier VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, multiplier, code

I'm trying to build a 4-bit Booth multiplier using VHDL. I don't know why, but the process block is executed just once. The state does change from idle to busy then it doesn't work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;


entity booth_mult is
  port(
    clk     : in std_logic;
    start   : in std_logic:='0';
    n_reset : in std_logic:='0';
    mcand   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    mplier  : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    done    : out std_logic :='0';
    product : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :="00000000"
    );
end booth_mult;
```

Comment: The 2nd process sensitivity list is incomplete. Change to VHDL 2008 or later to use the keyword all in the sensitivty list.

Comment: @HKOB : added 'all' to the sensitivity list. still runs the same.

Comment: (severed from [revision 1](/revisions/411263/1).)

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a full answer, but there are a lot of things I spotted from a first look.

In your testbench, you assign `mplier` to a 1-bit value of `"0"`, when it's a vector 4 bits in length.

Your component declaration contains a generic, but that is not included in the actual entity multipler entity.

In your multiplier entity, the `next_count` signal isn't being used anywhere which might be why you're not advancing like you expect. `next_result_reg` and `prod_reg` are also not being used.

`accum` is not being initialized correctly, and has `X` values during simulation.

These are just a few things to start looking at. There may be other things I didn't see at first glance.

Maybe you've already done this, but if not, it would help to draw out what you're trying to do before even touching the VHDL. Then once you have a solid plan drawn out, come back and give it another shot.

Comment: I did got this working there was a problem with the state machine structure.

Comment: @V.Singh: you may answer your own question for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed your state machine slightly and now it is working
but the way you are calculating "accum" is not good and need to be revised

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY booth_mult IS
   GENERIC( 
      W : integer := 4
   );
   PORT( 
      clk     : IN     std_logic;
      mcand   : IN     std_logic_vector (W-1 DOWNTO 0);
      mplier  : IN     std_logic_vector (W-1 DOWNTO 0);
      n_reset : IN     std_logic;
      start   : IN     std_logic;
      done    : OUT    std_logic;
      product : OUT    std_logic_vector (2*W-1 DOWNTO 0)
   );

-- Declarations

END booth_mult;

--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ARCHITECTURE arch OF booth_mult IS

   -- Architecture Declarations
   signal next_count,count :integer := 0;
   signal mcand_reg: std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0); 
   signal prod_reg, accum: std_logic_vector(2*W-1 downto 0);
   signal next_result_reg,result_reg: std_logic_vector(W downto 0);

   TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (
      IDLE,
      BUSY,
      Muldone
   );

   -- Declare current and next state signals
   SIGNAL current_state : STATE_TYPE;
   SIGNAL next_state : STATE_TYPE;

BEGIN

   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   clocked_proc : PROCESS ( 
      clk
   )
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   BEGIN
      IF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
         IF (n_reset = '0') THEN
            current_state <= IDLE;
         ELSE
            current_state <= next_state;

            -- Combined Actions
            CASE current_state IS
               WHEN IDLE => 
                      mcand_reg <= mcand;
                      accum <= (others => '0');
                      result_reg(4 downto 1) <= mplier;
                      result_reg(0) <= '0';
                      count <= 0;
               WHEN BUSY => 
                  case result_reg(1 downto 0) is     
                    when "01" =>    accum<=(accum(7 downto 5) + mcand)&accum(3 downto 0);accum<= accum(7) & accum(7 downto 1);
                    when "10" =>    accum<=(accum(7 downto 5) - mcand)&accum(3 downto 0);accum<= accum(7) & accum(7 downto 1);          
                    when others =>  accum<= accum(7) & accum(7 downto 1);
                    end case;

                    next_result_reg <= (result_reg(4) & result_reg(4 downto 1));
                    count <= count + 1;
               WHEN OTHERS =>
                  NULL;
            END CASE;
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END PROCESS clocked_proc;

   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   nextstate_proc : PROCESS ( 
      accum,
      count,
      current_state,
      n_reset,
      start
   )
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   BEGIN

      -- Combined Actions
      CASE current_state IS
         WHEN IDLE => 
            done <= '0';
            IF (n_reset = '1' and start ='1') THEN 
               next_state <= BUSY;
            ELSE
               next_state <= IDLE;
            END IF;
         WHEN BUSY => 
            IF (count = 4) THEN 
               next_state <= Muldone;
            ELSE
               next_state <= BUSY;
            END IF;
         WHEN Muldone => 
            product <= accum(7) & accum(7 downto 1);
            done <= '1' ;
            next_state <= IDLE;
         WHEN OTHERS =>
            next_state <= IDLE;
      END CASE;
   END PROCESS nextstate_proc;

END arch;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.I did get it working now the problem was with the state machine.